# Alter the login form

Tags: 8, forms

I am new to Drupal and I need to alter the login form add extra validation fields with adding two more date of birth and email id using ***hook_form_alter***. How do i do this. and how to find the login form ***$form_id***.

Comment: To add some informations to [Lia's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294393/95193) answer, here is some useful links for you: [alter form login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205700/how-do-i-alter-the-login-form) [alter form login and submit example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190703/how-to-alter-the-drupal8-user-login-form-inputs-and-validation) And the official doc with many [examples](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this is an example of a login form alter. Just adding some extra buttons here.
This is just an example as to how to go about the alter hook, about the validation fields I am not sure.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for login.
 */
function THEMENAME_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['reset_password'] = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Forgot your password?'),
    '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.pass'),
    '#id' => 'login-reset-password',
    '#weight' => 99,
  ];
  $form['register_user'] = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Create one.'),
    '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.register'),
    '#id' => 'login-user-register',
    '#weight' => 100,
  ];
  $form['register_user']['#prefix'] = "<div class=\"form-footer\"> <span>" . t("Don't have an account?") . "</span>";
  $form['register_user']['#suffix'] = "</div>";
  $form['title_page'] = [
    '#type' => 'label',
    '#title' => t('Log in'),
    '#weight' => -99,
  ];
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to add extra validation fields, a DOB field, and an email field. The code shown in this answer just shows how to add two links. For the OP, this is just useful to see the parameters for `hook_form_alter()`.